Words in my bookshelf
I like to put words in my bookshelf. This is a very special bookshelf though, because books don't fit in there.
My bookshelf has 3 layers, and different words can fit on different layers. Here are some examples:



Bottom Layer
Middle Layer
Top Layer




STATE
COUNTRY
FLAG


YELLOW
BROWN
BLACK


WEIGHT
NEWTON
MASS


EQUAL
TWENTY-ONE
ADD


DELETE
RETURN
BACK


LEG
BONE
HAND


QUARTER
PENNY
HALF


TOP
BOTTOM
ALL


WORDS
PROVERB
BLANK



Now that you've seen some examples, please tell me: which literary genre could I fit into two different layers of my bookshelf?

CSV version:
Bottom Layer,Middle Layer,Top Layer
STATE,COUNTRY,FLAG
YELLOW,BROWN,BLACK
WEIGHT,NEWTON,MASS
EQUAL,TWENTY-ONE,ADD
DELETE,RETURN,BACK
LEG,BONE,HAND
QUARTER,PENNY,HALF
TOP,BOTTOM,ALL
WORDS,PROVERB,BLANK


Bottom layer has words which

 do not contain letters on a keyboard's bottom row -> Z,X,C,V,B,N,M

Middle layer has words which

 do not contain letters on a keyboard's middle row -> A,S,D,F,G,H,J,K,L

Top layer has words which

 do not contain letters on a keyboard's top row -> Q,W,E,R,T,Y,U,I,O,P

So a literary genre which could fit in two different layers is

 poetry as this could go in the bottom or middle rows.

And noticed by J.E "books" doesn't fit in the bookshelf, because

 the word contains letters from all three rows.


You could also mention that rot13("obbxf" qbrfa'g svg va gur obbxfurys, orpnhfr gur jbeq pbagnvaf yrggref sebz nyy guerr ebjf).
